# Confusing JavaScript assignment syntax error

Tags: javascript

For some reason at least in the browsers console this is a valid expression which evaluates to x being equal to 1

```
{x} = {x:1}
```

However the same thing with a semicolon at the end throws the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Whats the exact error message?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` most likely

Comment: you must be getting error for the first statement alos

Comment: You need to write `var` in front, to make it work again. Like `var {x} = {x:1};`

Comment: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '=' ` obiously :)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey nope, no error thrown for the first one, can attach a screenshot if necessary but you can just check in chrome's console or whatever. The first one does not throw one the other one does.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. It's a pretty good question about a confounding and unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write `var` in front:

```js
var {x} = {x:2};
console.log(x);
```

Comment: I know that this is not throwing an error and this is a correct way to assign value to x in this case, I am wondering why a lack of ```var``` or ```let``` in the same statement with a semicolon throws an error, and the same statement without one doesn't.

Comment: @DaveDemirkhanyan The spec might require `var` or `let` to destructure. It might lead to ambiguous cases otherwise, or something. It might make parsing more difficult too, since you'd have to get passed the destructure braces to see if it's defining literal or destructuring and object.